# A bug while inserting a serializer in the raw data section, Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Showing below is a product (with id 65) containing two categories (with id 1 and id 66), the bug is that I didn't add the category of id 1 when creating the product I only added the category of id 66 ( in the 'Raw Data' section) , so each time I add a new product with a category inside , the category of id 1 gets added automatically to the list of categories. That's the bug !

```
{
    "id": 65,
    "product_code": "kdhjkfh",
    "name": "klfjkj",
    "quantity": 12,
    "price": 12,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ksjdf",
            "products": [
                65
            ],
            "categories": [
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "name": "dkllj",
            "products": [
                65
            ],
            "categories": []
        }
    ]
}
```

the serializers.py part of the product

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', "product_code", "name", "quantity", "price", 'categories')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_data = validated_data.pop('categories')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        dicti={}
        for items in category_data:
            for key, value in items.items() :
                dicti[key] = value
        if 'id' in dicti:
            x= product.categories.get_or_create(id = dicti['id'])
            product.categories.set(x)
        return product
```

Does anybody has any idea why the category of id 1 gets added automatically ?

**EDITED**

The post model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The product data entered in the raw data section before making the POST request

```
{
    "id": 65,
    "product_code": "kdhjkfh",
    "name": "klfjkj",
    "quantity": 12,
    "price": 12,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 66,
            "name": "dkllj",
            "products": [
                65
            ],
            "categories": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What sort of relationship do product and categories have? many-to-many? please add your model. Also, add the post data

Comment: @Ken4scholars it's a many to many , you can check the edited question, although I didn't understand what you really meant by the post data , do you mean what I have added to the end of the question ?